# C - array of pointers to struct, syntax

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I've got a struct A and an array of pointers to instances of that struct
I'm trying to access a member directly from the array but I don't know what's the right syntax to do it :

```
struct A  
{  
  int a;  
  void** b;  
}

A* p = (A*) malloc(sizeof(A));  
p->b = (A**) malloc(sizeof(A*) * 3);

//
// something is done
//

int c;

A* test = p->b[0];
c = test->a;
```

Basically what I'm asking is how do I get rid of the intermediate A* test so I can assign the value of c in one line ?

Comment: Why `void**` and not `struct A **`?

Comment: That's irrelevent.
I just need a void for what I'm doing but not showing here.
The problem lies in the two last lines

Comment: `p->b = (A**) malloc(sizeof(A*) * 3);` is ill-formed, the compiler should complain

Comment: Are you sure you aren't using a C++ compiler?

Answer (score 2):

Just do

```
int c = ((struct A*) (p->b[0]))->a;
```

---

Defining

```
struct A  
{  
  int a;  
  struct A ** b;  
}
```

this would do

```
int c = p->b[0]->a;
```

Comment: That works, you rock ! So that void was kinda relevent after all ?

Comment: @user3548298: That's why I asked. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You can do :

```
c = ((A*) (p->b[0]))->a;
```

Comment: You cannot, as `A` is not a type in C.